# Magento 2 How to override Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tabs

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add new tab for product attribute configuration....Tab name is 
manage icon and quantity range status show in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has an answer I am also interested.

I tested the overload of the di.xml but without effect ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tabs" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tabs" />
</config>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.... @Benoit Decoster